# xcode opens new storyboards with no screen template

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

recently xcode suddenly started showing me empty storyboard like there is no template for an iphone screen or anything i re-downloaded the app and the problem is still there

[just like this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBI9e.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seams really counterintuitive indeed, Xcode used to have it's "Components" Library inside storyboard's window, now you have to:

- Navigate through Xcode's top bar > `View` > `Show Library`

or just use bellow shortcut:

- ⇧(Shift) + ⌘(Command) + L